# How to make a function memorize 2 variable function values?

Tags: python, list, function, recursion, memoization

I want to improve the performance of a recursive calculation of values

```
n = 100

def T(n,k):
    q = 0
    if n == 0 and k == 0:
        return(1)
        q = 1
    if k>n or n<0:
        return(0)
        q = 1
    if q != 1:
        return(T(n-1,k-1)+n*T(n-1,k))

for i in range(n):
    for n in range(i+1):
        print(T(i,n))
    print("*********")
```

However, I've only found ways to do this with functions that only take 1 argument, like this:

```
def mem(f):
    memory = {}
    def inner_function(x):
        if x not in memory:            
            memory[x] = f(x)
            return memory[x]
        else:
            return memory[x]
    return inner_function

@mem
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

I was thinking of doing a 2d array, but I don't know yet (assuming it's possible) how the idea of doing so, with lists of lists, would help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What does this recursive function do, exactly? Single-letter vars aren't helping me out much.... There is dead code after `return` on two branches. In general, though, if you want to memoize functions with multi args, just add more args to `inner_function` and hash them as a tuple in `memo`. It can be complicated if those args are mutable or otherwise not hashable, though, which doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: `if q != 1:` is always true, also....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily extend your `mem` decorator to work with variable `*args` parameters, looking them up in the `memory`. This would work with `**kwargs`, too, you'd have to convert them to a hashable type though, e.g. `frozenset` of `tuples`. And of course all parameters must be hashable for this.

```
def mem(f):
    memory = {}
    def inner_function(*args):
        if args not in memory:            
            memory[args] = f(*args)
        return memory[args]
    return inner_function
```

Tested with your `T` function, works fine. In practice, however, you might still want to use `functools.lru_cache`.

Comment: @Barmar You are right, I somehow assumed it to be a list and did not check.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) for this

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def T(n,k):
    q = 0
    if n == 0 and k == 0:
        return(1)
        q = 1
    if k>n or n<0:
        return(0)
        q = 1
    if q != 1:
        return(T(n-1,k-1)+n*T(n-1,k))
```

You can use this decorator to memoize function calls, with this function in particular this will save up to the `maxsize` most recent calls.

Note in this particular case, the **vast** majority of the time is actually spent writing to console because of your `print` statements. If you remove this (but still leave your `T(i,n)` invocation) your code will complete almost instantaneously.

Comment: pro-tip: use mutable default arguments to create stateful functions which can then effectively cache themselves. 
Not actually a pro-tip
Never actually do this.

Comment: You can also use `@cache` to make the cache unbounded.